# Adding CNAME entry to nginx for cdn rewrite

Tags: nginx, cname-record

I am using apache + nginx (for serving static content) and just bought a CDN. I have added a CNAME entry to my CDN URL, which should be cdn.example.com and pointing to the original cdn url. xxx.netdna-cdn.com/

But probably because of my nginx vhost file when I run cdn.example.com, it opens the first server entry site in my vhost file.

I have multiple sites in my server. 
I have added CNAME from CPanel DNS editor as well.

No luck, so I think I need to add something in the vhost.conf.

Comment: CNAMEs do not configure your web server for you. You need to setup a vhost for the cdn.example.com address.

Answer (score 0):

No chances are your DNS is still cached so it is still hitting your webserver and not the CDN's server. Make sure your dns is resolving correctly on your computer

```
 nslookup cdn.domain.com
```

If it is make sure you have no hosts entry hardcoding the cdn host to an IP since your browser will use that before asking DNS for the IP.

Comment: nop not added anything in vhost for the cdn.domain.com ..

Answer (score 0):

If you're planning to redirect cdn.example.com to your CDN url, you'll need to add a CNAME entry from your DNS control panel. Something to the effect of:

```
cdn    IN    CNAME  xxx.netdna-cdn.com
```

You don't need to configure any vhost at your end.